# Codeigniter cannot load libraries

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Initially, I thought I had a problem with loading libraries due to using Modular Extensions inside Codeigniter.

However I have discovered even with a clean install of codeigniter I am unable to load libraries such as the `Session library` or even the Migration library.

I always get similar error messages usually to do with loading files.

Here is my error message I have when using the Session library.

**Note:** If i don't use libraries everything works fine.

**Error:**

> A PHP Error was encountered
>        Severity: Warning
>        Message: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Invalid argument
>        Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php
>        Line Number: 117
>
> Backtrace:
>        File: index.php
>        Line: 301
>        Function: require_once
>
> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>        Type: Exception
>        Message: Session: Configured save path '' is not a directory, doesn't exist or cannot be created.
>
> Filename: \system\libraries\Session\drivers\Session_files_driver.php
>        Line Number: 119
>
> Backtrace:
>        File: index.php
>        Line: 301
>        Function: require_once

I feel like this is some form of permissions issue, but whether I am using AMPPS, MAMP (Windows) or XAMP I always get this problem.

Does anyone have any ideas

**OS**: Windows 8.1

**Webserver**: AMPPS/MAMP(Windows)/XAMP - All have the problem.

**Codeigniter**: v3.0.0

**Config**:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

---

**EDIT**:

Resolved.

It's important now that you use the CI3 Documentation, When using the database method for sessions please ensure you use the updated SQL to create the table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (

        `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
        `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        `data` blob NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

As found [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#session-drivers). I hope this helps anyone out with similar problems.

Also for the initial problem if you are using the `files` driver please ensure you set the `$config['sess_save_path']` to something like `'ci_sessions'` or wherever you wish to store. Please see @Tpojka answer for more information.

Comment: how are you loading the sesssion library?

Comment: $autoload['libraries'] = array('session'); autoload.php

Comment: where did you download Codeigniter from? There are some corrupt CI downloads out there.

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/ - it works perfectly on my MAC OS at home but on my windows it has these what appears to be permission errors.

Comment: Also, how is your environment like? Windows/Mac? what versions?, etc...

Comment: This particular machine is Windows 8.1 and i'm using AMPPS.

Comment: Lastly, what CI version?

Comment: Codeigniter version 3.0.0

Comment: Im not too familiar with Windows 8.1, but what if you turn off User Access Control (UAC)? have you tried that?

Comment: I always have UAC off, so that can't be the problem.

Comment: What do you have in config.php section where it loads the following: `$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 1800;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;`

Comment: Please see my edit for configs :)

Comment: Im looking into it, but have no idea what this is about. It works well on my local machine. Have you migrated these files from your mac to your PC? or did you download the files from codeigniter.com directly to your PC?

Comment: Literally a fresh download i changed only the library to include sessions and it doesn't work. No matter what software i use for apache I get this problem.

Comment: **Read the entire "Session Variables" comment block** within your `config.php` file.  This block is located right above the line, `$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';`.

Comment: Please do not post the same question more than once.  Duplicate of [Cannot load libraries when using HMVC Modular extensions with CI3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29422243/cannot-load-libraries-when-using-hmvc-modular-extensions-with-ci3)

Comment: Going to delete the other one. It's not the same as I thought it was due to HMVC And it's not. So will delete the question.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> **Message:** Session: Configured save path '' is not a directory, doesn't exist or cannot be created.

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
```

Try to set this one.

For me This one worked

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = '/tmp';
```

Comment: Why must I set a path?

Comment: How did CI2 handle sessions? Files too?

Comment: I just read error and suggest solution. Afaik, sessions are totally rewritten in CI3. Also, I am using DB for storing such a information, so you can try and let us know if solved. :)

Comment: @mdixon18, FYI, the "Session Variables" comments section embedded right inside the CodeIgniter `config.php` file tells you all about each option in great detail.  You **cannot** set `'sess_save_pat'` to `NULL` while having `'sess_driver'` set to `'files'`.  Quoting: *"For the 'files' driver, **it's a path to a writable directory**.  WARNING: Only absolute paths are supported!"*

Comment: well this seems to work: $config['sess_save_path'] = '/ci_session';

Comment: How can I use the database method? As i would like to do this way too

Comment: If you have set your DB credentials already, you can follow [this section](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver) on [Session library page](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html). If no, first set [DB configuration](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/configuration.html) in your application. In documentation, it is suggested to use MySQL or PostreSQL driver. If you face some issue, post it here or in new topic or very likely find an already posted. :)

Comment: Apparently you can set up database for just migration and sessions, how can you do that?

Comment: How do you mean? Do you have connected db already or not? In both cases you can follow my previous answer. Beside that, CI is very well documented with basic examples of pretty much everything. What have you done already after reading documentation? What is exact issue? Can you post code of that or error message produced?

Comment: Well you have to use MySQL for migrations and I'd rather use mysqli for everything else

Comment: Meant about MySQL platform of DB. Driver is mysqli (notice lower case required by CI), you are right for that. MySQLi is encouraged to be used.

Comment: Can we set database settings in a controller/model so that say the migration controller/model has it's own database driver etc. Because that would be really cool.

Comment: I would suggest you to read DB Reference in documentation. It is very well documented how to set credentials for more than one db connection and use it in dinamically in application. If you have some doubt about that, it would be good to make another topic (if searching for one doesn't give relevant). Just use search query in google "codeigniter dynamically changing database" and first three links will be topics on SOF. ;)

Comment: @Tpojka just tried out your database method for sessions and now I have another issue:

Fatal error: Call to a member function row() on a non-object in C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\CMS\barebones\system\libraries\Session\drivers\Session_database_driver.php on line 156
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function row() on a non-object

Filename: drivers/Session_database_driver.php

Line Number: 156

Backtrace:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74462/discussion-between-tpojka-and-mdixon18).

Answer (score 95):

Working code;

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
```

This allows to execute the script.

Comment: That one worked well. Setting the sess_save_path to NULL was default and it didn't work. As I'm running CI on a hosting, your solution worked well.

Comment: I enter this string, and the page loops

Comment: This is the right answer.. with all respect, I really don't know why one choose Tpojka's answer as correct if in your own words he said that just had read the error and only suggested an option.

Answer (score 10):

This Code is working for on my MACOS for session error :

You need to add this code into config.php file

you need to replace `NULL` with `sys_get_temp_dir()`

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
```

My error was :

> Warning: Uncaught Exception: Session: Configured save path '' is not a directory, doesn't exist or cannot be created. in /Library/WebServer/Documents/ci/fuse/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_files_driver.php:138 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: CI_Session_files_driver->open('', 'ci_session') #1 /Library/WebServer/Documents/ci/fuse/system/libraries/Session/Session.php(143): session_start() #2 /Library/WebServer/Documents/ci/fuse/system/core/Loader.php(1281): CI_Session->__construct() #3 /Library/WebServer/Documents/ci/fuse/system/core/Loader.php(1174): CI_Loader->_ci_init_library('Session', 'CI_', NULL, 'session') #4 /Library/WebServer/Documents/ci/fuse/system/core/Loader.php(1037): CI_Loader->_ci_load_stock_library('Session', 'Session/', NULL, NULL) #5 /Library/WebServer/Documents/ci/fuse/system/core/Loader.php(1082): CI_Loader->_ci_load_library('Session', NULL, NULL) #6 /Library/WebServer/Documents/ci/fuse/system/core/Loader.php(218): CI_Loader->_ci_load_library('Session', NULL, NULL) #7 /Library/WebServe in /Library/WebServer/Documents/ci/fuse/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_files_driver.php on line 138
>
> Fatal error: session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: user (path: ) in /Library/WebServer/Documents/ci/fuse/system/libraries/Session/Session.php on line 143

Answer (score 6):

1. Open config.php and create a session folder with `0755` permission.
2. Update below code variable

   ```
   $config['sess_save_path'] =  __DIR__ . '/session';
   ```

Comment: a small description as to why your code solves the issue might make it a so much better answer

Answer (score 5):

I also run into this problem today.

Thank you Sparky and Trojka, setting my config to use database instead file made my CI app working perfectly, both on my local server and live one.

Here is how:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';       // changed from file
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions'; // table name
```

There is MySQL for table creation in link Trojka posted.

Comment: Can you share this method?

Comment: Only this isn't really an answer.

Comment: Ah yeah ofc, I read this. I'm hoping there is a way to include multiple database methods for different things such as the application and migrations.

Comment: You are welcome @zbrka. I only hope your nickname doesn't represent your code. :D

Answer (score 2):

From CI3 Docs:
By default, the Files Driver will be used when a session is initialized, because it is the most safe choice and is expected to work everywhere (virtually every environment has a file system).

So default thing works good on windows environment but on mac and linux systems I have faced similar issues.

Thing that worked for me without switching to Database:

Step 1: create session directory with proper permissions:

```
mkdir /<path to your application directory>/ci_sessions/
chmod 0700 /<path to your application directory>/ci_sessions/
chown _www /<path to your application directory>/ci_sessions/
```

Take care of apache username it varies like: www-data, _www, apache etc.

Step 2: Set absolute path for sess_save_path config:
(Mine on Mac looked like below)

```
$config['sess_save_path'] ='/Library/WebServer/Documents/App/ci_sessions/';
```