# codeigniter sess_driver and path

Tags: codeigniter, session

I am trying to upload my `codeigniter 3` site to godaddy, but I keep getting errors messages such as `Session: Configured save path 'C:\Windows\Temp' is not writable by the PHP process.`.

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431910/codeigniter-cannot-load-libraries) question and the codeigniter database driver [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver) but so far nothing.

I created a ci_sessions table in my database, set the driver to database and the path to `ci_sessions` but I then get a fatal error. I tried setting the driver to files and the path to a ci_sessions folder I created but it can't find it but I'm not sure I created it correctly, I used `$config['sess_save_path'] = '{{site_path}}/application/ci_sessions';`

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Ok, so I started with a fresh version of `codeigniter 3` and set the driver to database and path to ci_sessions and it works, but when I use `if(!empty($this->session->userdata("user_id"))` it causes the fatal error, any ideas?

Comment: $config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried this though and I get `Session: Configured save path 'ci_sessions' is not writable by the PHP process.`

Comment: Did you autoload session library

Answer (score 19):

On your session save path looks like you are trying to save it to folder

create the a folder in application called ci_sessions make it 0700

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'ci_sessions/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

If you need to put it into database

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database'; // Change files to database
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions'; // This will be your database table for sessions
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

For MYSQL Database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
    `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `data` blob NOT NULL,
    KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

Comment: What to do in case of files, i am using files and my path is by default null

Comment: I tried everything above. Session is being expired after redirection. Working well in chrome(mac) but having issue in safari(MAC). But for many of the users chrome also having issue. Please advise. 

I tried to debug, session is being created, but when page is redirected to somewhere else, it expires. 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ParmendraSingh have you found the issue, I am facing a similar problem, when refreshing or redirecting, the session expires and redirects to login. If you found any solution please help.