# Codeigniter 3 Docker Compose Setup

Tags: php, codeigniter, docker-compose, session-variables

I am currently working with WAMP on my computer, but I would like to move over to docker in order to make the Codeigniter application's setup easier. I am using CodeIgniter 3 which I have setup to use the HMVC model. On the docker setup, I can get to the index page of the whole application from the browser, but I get several errors from the internal system files of Codeigniter.

Here are the errors I am getting:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: mkdir(): Invalid path

Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php

Line Number: 136

Backtrace:

File: /var/www/html/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php
Line: 173
Function: _ci_load_library

File: /var/www/html/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php
Line: 192
Function: library

File: /var/www/html/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php
Line: 153
Function: libraries

File: /var/www/html/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php
Line: 65
Function: initialize

File: /var/www/html/application/third_party/MX/Base.php
Line: 55
Function: __construct

File: /var/www/html/application/third_party/MX/Base.php
Line: 60
Function: __construct

File: /var/www/html/application/third_party/MX/Controller.php
Line: 6
Function: require

File: /var/www/html/application/third_party/MX/Modules.php
Line: 123
Function: include_once

File: /var/www/html/application/modules/user/controllers/User.php
Line: 5
Function: spl_autoload_call

File: /var/www/html/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once


Warning: Uncaught Exception: Session: Configured save path '' is not a directory, doesn't exist or cannot be created. in /var/www/html/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_files_driver.php:138 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: CI_Session_files_driver->open('', 'ci_session') #1 /var/www/html/system/libraries/Session/Session.php(143): session_start() #2 /var/www/html/system/core/Loader.php(1281): CI_Session->__construct() #3 /var/www/html/system/core/Loader.php(1174): CI_Loader->_ci_init_library('Session', 'CI_', NULL, 'session') #4 /var/www/html/system/core/Loader.php(1037): CI_Loader->_ci_load_stock_library('Session', 'Session/', NULL, NULL) #5 /var/www/html/system/core/Loader.php(1082): CI_Loader->_ci_load_library('Session', NULL, NULL) #6 /var/www/html/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php(173): CI_Loader->_ci_load_library('Session', NULL, NULL) #7 /var/www/html/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php(192): MX_Loader->library('session') #8 /var/www/html/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php(153): MX_Loader->lib in /var/www/html/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_files_driver.php on line 138

Fatal error: session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: user (path: ) in /var/www/html/system/libraries/Session/Session.php on line 143
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/system/core/Exceptions.php:271)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 570

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error

Message: session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: user (path: )

Filename: Session/Session.php

Line Number: 143

Backtrace:
```

Here are my config variables for the session:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

I would prefer to not to have to save any session information to a file if that is possible. When working in WAMP this configuration worked just fine.

Here is my docker compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  apache:
    image: php:7.0-apache
    hostname: apache
    ports:
    - "80:80" # normal php port for trafic and functionality
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    hostname: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306" # mysql connection port
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER_FILE: var/lib/mysql-user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE: var/lib/mysql-user-p
      MYSQL_DATABASE_FILE: var/lib/mysql-db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: var/lib/mysql-root-p
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    links:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - "8183:80" # phpmyadmin login page
    environment:
      PMA_USER: user
      PMA_PASSWORD: password
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
```

-app: contains codeigniter files

-data: contains a folder for the placement of mysql data and a few config files.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You have your session save path null don't leave it blank refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37776545/codeigniter-sess-driver-and-path/37779697#37779697

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By following Mr. ED's advice, I fixed the problem:I did not leave the session field blank and decided to use the database in order to store the data.