# An uncaught Exception was encountered in xampp

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, xampp

I get this error when i try and open my application 
nothing seems to work can someone help me? i'm not a professional developper

> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: UnexpectedValueException
>
> Message: Session: Configured driver 'files' was not found. Aborting.
>
> Filename:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\reseauxfinal\system\libraries\Session\Session.php
>
> Line Number: 233
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\reseauxfinal\application\controllers\Authentification.php
>   Line: 7 Function: __construct
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\reseauxfinal\index.php Line: 320 Function:
>   require_once

Comment: if your question related to codeigniter, this link may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33898705/9501353