# Codeigniter : Session: Configured save path is not a directory

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am trying to transfer my website to another server.
I transferred all data files to another server and
and I imported db files by phpMyAdmin correctly.

then I received error log as

> [16-Jun-2018 12:21:52 UTC] PHP Warning: Uncaught Exception: Session: Configured save path '/kfive/sessions' is not a directory, doesn't exist or cannot be created. in /home/u620816326/public_html/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_files_driver.php:138
>
> Stack trace:
>   0 [internal function]: CI_Session_files_driver->open('/kfive/sessions', 'ci_session')
>
> 1 /home/u620816326/public_html/system/libraries/Session/Session.php(143): session_start()
>
> 2 /home/u620816326/public_html/system/core/Loader.php(1285): CI_Session->__construct()
>
> 3 /home/u620816326/public_html/system/core/Loader.php(1178): CI_Loader->_ci_init_library('Session', 'CI_', NULL, 'session')
>
> 4 /home/u620816326/public_html/system/core/Loader.php(1043): CI_Loader->_ci_load_stock_library('Session', 'Session/', NULL, NULL)
>
> 5 /home/u620816326/public_html/system/core/Loader.php(1089): CI_Loader->_ci_load_library('Session', NULL, NULL)
>
> 6 /home/u620816326/public_html/system/core/Loader.php(218): CI_Loader->_ci_load_library('Session', NULL, NULL)
>   7 /home/u620816326/public_html/system/core/Lo in /home/u620816326/public_html/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_files_driver.php on line 138
>
> [16-Jun-2018 12:21:52 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: user (path: /kfive/sessions) in /home/u620816326/public_html/system/libraries/Session/Session.php on line 143

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Show your `$config['sess_save_path']`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter cannot load libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431910/codeigniter-cannot-load-libraries)

Answer (score 1):

In your CI Project config `appliaction/config/config.php` there is a line

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = '/kfive/sessions';
```

This is where your session data gets saved and its an absolute path. So you need to create a directory like this with full rights to solve this issue.

Comment: Gopakumar Gopalan Thank you.
I created /kfive/sessions directory but still displayed HTTP ERROR 500.
My website URL is www.dobitpoker.com

Comment: Do your /kfive/sessions directory have full rights? (777) If so check the server error for the details of 500 error.